# Looping through a sorted dictionary un sorts it.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a dictionary that I have sorted. My problem is when I loop through it gets unsorted again.

```
    //sort the poiIDArray so it appears alphabetically
NSArray *sortedValues = [[self.pois allValues] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSMutableDictionary *orderedDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
for(NSString *valor in sortedValues){
    for(NSString *clave in [self.pois allKeys]){
        if ([valor isEqualToString:[self.pois valueForKey:clave]]) {
            [orderedDictionary setValue:valor forKey:clave];
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"ordered dic: %@",orderedDictionary);


//loop through dic and get names. 
for(NSString *key in orderedDictionary) {

    NSLog(@"%@",key);

}
```

Here is my log.

```
2012-10-26 11:49:35.221 CPOP Test 4[1277:c07] ordered dic: {
"Badger Burgers" = 5;
"Costa Coffee" = 4;
"Spiffing Drinks" = 6;
"Vals Vegetables" = 7;
}
2012-10-26 11:49:35.221 CPOP Test 4[1277:c07] Costa Coffee
2012-10-26 11:49:35.222 CPOP Test 4[1277:c07] Spiffing Drinks
2012-10-26 11:49:35.222 CPOP Test 4[1277:c07] Badger Burgers
2012-10-26 11:49:35.222 CPOP Test 4[1277:c07] Vals Vegetables
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries are by definition unordered. If you need a particular order, use an array.

Comment: So how does the loop work? Does it just pick a random object out of dictionary? I would have thought that It would start at the first object and loop through so if it was in order it would come out in order.

Comment: The loop actually requests all keys, and returns that as an array (unsorted), after that it iterates all keys and requests the object. If you want to sort, you can request the keys, sort that array and then loop that sorted array.